# Proof by reductio ad absurdum in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle, proof

I understand how `ccontr` works, however I am unsure how (or even if it is possible) to use it on a lemma declared with assumption(s).

Take this simple example, all is good:

```
lemma l1: "A⊆B ⟶ A ∩ B = A"
proof(rule ccontr)
  assume "¬(A⊆B ⟶ A ∩ B = A)"
  then show False
    by auto
qed
```

Technically, the lemma is equivalent (**Note) to:

```
lemma l2: 
  assumes P: "A⊆B"
    shows Q: "A ∩ B = A"
proof(rule ccontr)
  assume "¬(P ⟶ Q)"
  then show False ...
qed
```

gives an error on the "then show..." line

```
Failed to refine any pending goal 
Local statement fails to refine any pending goal
Failed attempt to solve goal by exported rule:
  (¬ (P ⟶ Q)) ⟹ False
```

It seems that I cannot use `ccontr` in the `assumes... shows...` version (l2). I have tried to use `assume Q ∧ ¬P`, with the same error.
Is there a way to go on with some sort of proof of the form "assume (Q and ~P) show False therefore lemma is correct"?

(**Note): Side question: is my assumption that lemmas l1 and l2 are logically equivalent? Is there something that makes them dramatically different from each other (in Isabelle)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should negate what you claim (in `shows`) and then prove that given the assumptions this leads to `False`:

```
lemma l2: 
assumes P: "A⊆B"
shows "A ∩ B = A"
proof (rule ccontr)
  assume "¬(A ∩ B = A)"
  with P show False by auto
qed
```

I checked this in Isabelle/ZF but it should be the same in Isabelle/HOL.

As for the side question strictly speaking these two forms are not logically the same as the first one uses the object logic implication `⟶` while the second one uses ==> from meta-logic. Both forms express the same idea however and I personally prefer the second one as it is more readable and works better with automation in Isabelle.

Comment: Please use ==> as much as possible or assumes. The entire machinery (OF, simplifier, …) require that.

Comment: Thank you, both! Yes, empirically I figured out that assumes...shows... is better than -->. I just missed the --> vs ==>, thank you for pointing it out.